# How to draw arc through 3 points

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uibezierpath

How to draw an arc as shown in the image as suppose i have a UIView as the middle point of the line which is movable.

[image]

[image]

i had store line's start point in CGPoint name lineStartPoint and end point as lineEndPoint.

the moving object can be accessed through CGPoint named movingPoint.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: are you asking to draw an arc between two points ?

Comment: yes, through the mid point movement

Comment: did u try using the bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake ?

Comment: yes but not able to achieve same as shown in the image

Comment: pls update your question with what you have tried and point out the specifc issue you are facing!

Comment: And while editing your question remove the `Xcode` tag as this is only for IDE questions.

Comment: Is your problem to calculate the center and radius of the arc?

Comment: Yes you're right, unable to draw an arc having that concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example how to calculate the required parameters for the `bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // for example
    CGPoint lineStartPoint = {100,100};
    CGPoint lineEndPoint =   {100,200};
    CGPoint movingPoint =    {30,150};


    CGFloat eps = 1e-5;

    CGVector v1 = {movingPoint.x-lineEndPoint.x, movingPoint.y-lineEndPoint.y};
    CGFloat dist1 = sqrt(v1.dx*v1.dx + v1.dy*v1.dy);
    v1.dx = v1.dx/dist1;
    v1.dy = v1.dy/dist1;

    CGVector v2 = {movingPoint.x-lineStartPoint.x, movingPoint.y-lineStartPoint.y};
    CGFloat dist2 = sqrt(v2.dx*v2.dx + v2.dy*v2.dy);
    v2.dx = v2.dx/dist2;
    v2.dy = v2.dy/dist2;


    CGFloat det = v1.dx*v2.dy - v1.dy*v2.dx;
    if (fabs(det) < eps) {
        // the three points are collinear
        // TODO: draw a line from lineStartPoint to lineEndPoint
        return;
    }

    CGPoint mid1 = {(movingPoint.x+lineEndPoint.x)/2, (movingPoint.y+lineEndPoint.y)/2};
    CGPoint mid2 = {(movingPoint.x+lineStartPoint.x)/2, (movingPoint.y+lineStartPoint.y)/2};

    CGFloat b1 = v1.dx*mid1.x + v1.dy*mid1.y;
    CGFloat b2 = v2.dx*mid2.x + v2.dy*mid2.y;

    CGFloat centerX = v2.dy/det*b1 - v1.dy/det*b2;
    CGFloat centerY = -v2.dx/det*b1 + v1.dx/det*b2;

    CGPoint center = {centerX, centerY};
    CGFloat radius = sqrtf((movingPoint.x-center.x)*(movingPoint.x-center.x) + (movingPoint.y-center.y)*(movingPoint.y-center.y));
    CGFloat startAngle = atan2f(lineStartPoint.y-center.y, lineStartPoint.x-center.x);
    CGFloat movingAngle = atan2f(movingPoint.y-center.y, movingPoint.x-center.x);
    CGFloat endAngle = atan2f(lineEndPoint.y-center.y, lineEndPoint.x-center.x);

    BOOL isClockwise;
    if ((endAngle>startAngle && startAngle<movingAngle && movingAngle<endAngle) ||
        (endAngle<startAngle && !(endAngle<movingAngle && movingAngle<startAngle))) {
        isClockwise = YES;
    } else {
        isClockwise = NO;
    }


    //Show results

    CAShapeLayer* startPointLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    startPointLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:lineStartPoint radius:2 startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:YES].CGPath;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:startPointLayer];

    CAShapeLayer* endPointLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    endPointLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:lineEndPoint radius:2 startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:YES].CGPath;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:endPointLayer];

    CAShapeLayer* movingPointLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    movingPointLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:movingPoint radius:2 startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:YES].CGPath;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:movingPointLayer];

    CAShapeLayer* arcLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [arcLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    [arcLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
    arcLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:isClockwise].CGPath;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:arcLayer];

}
```

Comment: great answer, well one thing I want to know that if I want to move the movingPoint in such direction that creates 90 degrees corresponds to startPoint and endPoint? In short, moving point can be moved in the lines opposites direction only.

Comment: you can answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324822/restricting-pan-gesture-to-move-to-90-degree

Comment: I suggest to change the title of this question to 'Draw arc through 3 points'